# Qt pushbutton how to set an inner border

Tags: c++, qt

I use Qt and would like to create a pushbutton which looks like this:

[image: button with inner border]

I would like to use the stylesheet to create this, the white border color can be changed in different colors when needed, so a static image would not be very handy.

I have tried several stylesheets but I only can get the outer border, but not the inner border.

Thanks for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

stylesheets have limitations though.
You'd better overload the paint() handler.

Comment: Do you have example for this? I have an idea to use an qlabel as background and put on top qpushbutton with a border, the qlabel is then some what bigger and has black background color..

Comment: It sounds weird to use a QLabel to do what you've described above.
Your example above, is a simple transparent rounded black rectangle (no brush) with a thin black Pen. And finally, an opaque black rectangle inside.

You'd better read the documentation of the QPainter class. It provides all the methods that you might need for drawing polygons, paths, text etc.